# How to assign a value to a remote combobox and get a corresponding record in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

Lets say I have a pair of comboboxes backed by simple remote stores. I need to do some task when either combobox selection changes using selected records (not values).

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    reference: 'combo1',
    store: {
        type: 'MyStore1',
    },
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    listeners: {
        select: 'onSelect',
    },
},

{
    xtype: 'combo',
    reference: 'combo2',
    store: {
        type: 'MyStore2',
    },
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    listeners: {
        select: 'onSelect',
    },
},

//controller
doTask: function(record1, record2){
    console.log(record1.data.name, record2.data.name);
},

onSelect: function(combo, record) {
    var record1 = this.lookupReference('combo1').getSelection();
    var record2 = this.lookupReference('combo2').getSelection();
    this.doTask(record1, record2);
},
```

Now I am trying to trigger `doTask()` when having only `id` values, and ended up with something like this:

```
initData: function(id1, id2){
    this.lookupReference('combo1').setValue(id1);
    this.lookupReference('combo2').setValue(id2);

    var self = this;
    var waitTimer = Ext.Function.interval(function(){

        var record1 = this.lookupReference('combo1').getSelection();
        var record2 = this.lookupReference('combo2').getSelection();

        if(record1 && record2){
            window.clearInterval(waitTimer);

            this.doTask(record1, record2);
        }
    }, 100, self);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you using timer here ? Is it because do you want to wait till the records are loaded with those ids ?

Comment: Yes, getSelection() is null if called right away. Basically the issue is how to catch when a record for the current value is loaded, so I can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at whether your method works with values that you entered by typing. Not sure about that.

You could also use `findRecordByValue` wiht `getValue`. This searches the store using the value that was either chosen by selection or by typing. On the other hand this may come up blank, e.g. if the typed value is not in the store.